# $f_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly if and only if $(\|f_n\|)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded and $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**Problem**

Let $f_n\in C[0,1]$. Show that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly if and only if $(\|f_n\|)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded and $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$.

**Background**

Let $X$ be a normed space. Then the space $X'$ of all bounded linear functionals on $X$ is called the *dual space* of $X$. A sequence $(x_n)\in X$ *converges weakly* to $x\in X$ if for every $L\in X'$ we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} L(x_n)=L(x).$$

**Attempt**

For the reverse side, I think I can just use the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem. I am having trouble with the forward direction:

By the Riesz representation theorem, if $L\in (C[0,1])'$, then there is a borel measure $\mu$ so that 
$$L(f)=\int_0^1 f_n\  \mathrm{d}\mu.$$ Thus $f_n \rightarrow 0$ weakly if and only if $\int_0^1 f_n\  \mathrm{d}\mu\rightarrow 0.$

I am not sure where to go from here. I am hoping to set it up in such a way that the Banach Steinhaus theorem applies.

Comment: if $\mu$ is a Dirac measure then you get the pointwise convergence, right?

Comment: Yes but $\mu$ is not necessarily the dirac measure right? (I think I'm missing the significance of your comment)

Comment: I meant that we just choose $\mu$ as the Dirac measure, then we have $L \in X'$ and using the definition of weak convergence to get the pointwise convergence

Comment: You can just define a linear functional $L$ on $C[0,1]$ to be integration against the Dirac measure.

Comment: Oh my goodness I'm bad at this..... Thank you guys!

Comment: Although there is still the matter of boundedness that I am stuck on

Comment: with the boundedness you can use the Banach Steinhaus theorem. In fact you can prove that the weakly convergent sequences are bounded in general.

Comment: Re boundedness: a weakly convergent sequence is weakly bounded. Mackey's theorem says weakly bounded sets are bounded.